# Resizing a LVM physical volume on device /dev/sdb

Tags: lvm

When setting up my system I put in a second 1 TB drive in under `/dev/sdb`. I allocated 500GB to a physical volume directly onto the device and not a partition. This in turn was allocated to a logical volume called `lvhome`.

`pvscan` output:

```
PV /dev/sda2   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [118.74 GiB / 0    free]               
PV /dev/sdb    VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [931.51 GiB / 431.51 GiB free]         
Total: 2 [1.03 TiB] / in use: 2 [1.03 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

`pvdisplay` output:

```
    --- Physical volume ---               
  PV Name               /dev/sdb        
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg       
  PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 296.00 KiB                      
  Allocatable           yes             
  PE Size               4.00 MiB        
  Total PE              238467          
  Free PE               110467          
  Allocated PE          128000          
  PV UUID               3Sfs52-MX0g-m9Sq-hSkX-eFMf-ZjQY-UZogBl
```

`lsblk` output:

```
    sdb                     8:16     0   931.5G  0 disk  
       └─ubuntu--vg-lvhome  253:2    0   500G  0 lvm  /home
```

How do I go about adding the remaining 431.5GB of space on the device to a physical volume?

Comment: What's wrong with `pvresize`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 431 GB free you see in the PV output isn't a measure of how much space is unallocated to the PV, it is a measure of how much space on that PV is unallocated to LVs. If you run `vgscan` or `vgs` you will see the `ubuntu-vg` volume group has 431 GB free space, and you can either expand existing LVs (`lvextend`) or create new LVs (`lvcreate`) with that space. When you create a PV, you create that PV on the entire device, be it a partition or a whole-disk device, not on a smaller part of that device.

Comment: Shaun, John's last sentence illustrates where you went wrong when setting up the PV. Because you didn't use a partition, you only have a single block device to work with. That on it's own is fine, but then you only allocated a portion of the block device to the PV, and in doing so lost access to the remaining space on the drive; no block device to get to it.

Comment: Emmanuel - you cannot assign only part of a block device to a PV. `pvcreate` doesn't provide a way of doing that. Shaun has not lost access to the 'remainder' of the space, it is available in the VG as unallocated (meaning unallocated to any LVs).

Comment: John thanks for clarifying. So from what you are saying the PV is occupying the entire device. This is fine with me. I will now define an extra logical volume to access the remainder of the space in the PV.